# Xamarin Forms overlay image as background and place labels in different directions

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, label, landscape-portrait, absolutelayout

I would like to do something like the image below. I tried the absolute layout but it changes everything once it gets to the landscape . everything goes out to place again.

The final result will look like the image below (spirit - ticket part )

[image]

What I have so far

[image]

```
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#F0F0F0">

        <Grid Margin="10" RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

             <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Please review your reservation below" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
            <StackLayout  Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >

                <AbsoluteLayout>
                    <Image>
                        <AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Rectangle">
                                <On Platform="Android" Value=".5,.5,1.0,1.8" />
                                <On Platform="iOS" Value=".5,.10,1.8,1" />
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
                        <AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="AbsoluteLayoutFlags">
                                <On Platform="Android" Value="All" />
                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="All" />
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags>
                        <Image.Source>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
                                <On Platform="Android" Value="ticketone.png" />
                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="ticket.png" />
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                  <Label  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.1,99,.56,50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,WidthProportional" Text="ROOMSHFBHE GFDJHBCSJSJJ HJSDHSJ no snonnoj" TextColor="White"  FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"  LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
              </AbsoluteLayout>
```

What I get on landscape

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you actually want to do. The screenshot does not really help since it does not have your data in it. E.g. where should the "please review ...." text actually go?

Comment: I add an edit - I want to place all those labels inside the background image , the code only shows the first label on the black header.

Comment: the image you posted HAS NO RELATION to the code you posted.

Comment: I added again. please check. Thanks!

Comment: stop using all of the nested layouts and just use a simple grid

Comment: @Pxaml I think you can just use a simple StackLayout with background colour blue and add labels to that Statically or Dynamically based on your requirements and it should look like what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: the image I have to use is more complicated than what you see. it contains a lot of labels tru the image

Answer (score 0):

this creates a centered top label regardless of orientation

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Black"
    TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="center" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I added the grid and the text goes on top of the image. not sure how to get every label inside the background image.

Comment: make the image span the same rows and cols as the labels

Answer (score 0):

Use `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"` and set the `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds`  by calculating the percentage of X and Y of Image where you want the field views.

Comment: How do I calculate that ?